# No numbers in 'values', must provide a type

Tags: google-earth-engine, pixel, value-extraction

I'm facing an error when trying to export all the pixel value of a ImageCollection.
The error is :
[image]

But when I check the corresponding image in my dataset I don't see anything different from the other. Does anybody have an idea of what this due to ?

The function causing this error is the following :

```
function valuesByBands(img){
  var valuesByBand = img
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer : ee.Reducer.toList(),
    geometry : ROI, 
    crs : ModisProjection})
   var features = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.Array(valuesByBand.values())
    .transpose()
    .toList()
    .map(function (values) {
      return ee.Feature(null, ee.Dictionary.fromLists(
        valuesByBand.keys(), 
        values
      ))
    })
    )
     var SumFeatures = firstFeatures.merge(features)
    return SumFeatures
}

var firstFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.Array(valuesByBand.values())
    .transpose()
    .toList()
    .map(function (values) {
      return ee.Feature(null, ee.Dictionary.fromLists(
        valuesByBand.keys(), 
        values
      ))
    })
)
```

Here is the full code I use : https://code.earthengine.google.com/2b265a35b3b0653aa13459d720e65536

Comment: Could you provide a smaller reproducible example?

Comment: What do you mean by this ? Like maybe a smaller study time ? I tried with one year of data and I worked

Comment: There's too much going on in your script. It's likely that you don't need to do everything exactly as you are doing, e.g. calculate those specific indices, etc.. to be able to reproduce the error you are getting. A minimal reproducible example increases your chances of getting a good quality answer.

Comment: I edited my question